# Why my button interactable always set true?

Tags: unity

So I want to create a leaderoard system but use the Firebase anonymous login, the point is that when the first time, system will run out of UID it loads data from realtime database but if the username is empty the system won't load the data first and the Leaderboard button becomes non-interactable until the player fills in the fields. I've done all of that, but why the `Leaderboard button always interacrrable`?

[image]

so here the whole script:

```cs
  //Firebase variables
    [Header("Firebase")]
    public DependencyStatus dependencyStatus;
    public FirebaseAuth auth;
    public FirebaseUser User;
    public DatabaseReference DBreference;
    public static _FirebaseManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            instance = this;
        }

        _FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.InitializeFirebase();
        _FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.FetchFireBase();

        InitializeFirebase();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _MainMenuUI.instance.mainPanel.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance.FetchDataUpdate();
    }

    public void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
        AuthStateChanged(this, null);

    }

    void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //This checks if the user (your local user) is the same as the one from the auth
        if (auth.CurrentUser != User)
        {
            bool signedIn = User != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;
            User = auth.CurrentUser;
            if (signedIn)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed in " + User.UserId + " " + User.DisplayName);
                showDataBefore();
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine(SignAnynomiusly());
                showDataBefore();
            }
        }
    }

    //it does not directly log the user out but invalidates the auth
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        auth.StateChanged -= AuthStateChanged;
        auth = null;
    }

    public IEnumerator SignAnynomiusly()
    {
        var loginTask = auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => loginTask.IsCompleted);

        if (loginTask.Exception != null)
        {
            //If there are errors handle them
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {loginTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            User = loginTask.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", User.DisplayName, User.UserId);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator UpdateUsernameAuth(string _username)
    {
        //Create a user profile and set the username
        UserProfile profile = new UserProfile { DisplayName = _username };

        //Call the Firebase auth update user profile function passing the profile with the username
        var ProfileTask = User.UpdateUserProfileAsync(profile);
        //Wait until the task completes
        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => ProfileTask.IsCompleted);

        if (ProfileTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {ProfileTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            //Auth username is now updated
            Debug.Log("username added");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator UpdateUsernameDatabase(string _username)
    {
        //Set the currently logged in user username in the database
        var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").Child(User.UserId).Child("username").SetValueAsync(_username);

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            //Database username is now updated
            Debug.Log("username updated");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator UpdateScoreDatabase(int _highscore)
    {
        var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").Child(User.UserId).Child("highscore").SetValueAsync(_highscore);

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            //Database highscore is now updated
            Debug.Log("highscore added");
        }
    }

    public void showDataBefore()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadUserData());
        SaveUsernameTodatabase();
    }

    public void SaveUsernameTodatabase()
    {
        if (_MainMenuUI.instance.usernameRegisterField.text != null)
        {
            //update data 
            _MainMenuUI.instance.usernameRegisterField.text = User.DisplayName;
            StartCoroutine(UpdateUsernameDatabase(_MainMenuUI.instance.usernameRegisterField.text));
            _MainMenuUI.instance.leaderboardBtn.interactable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _MainMenuUI.instance.leaderboardBtn.interactable = false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator LoadUserData()
    {
        //Get the currently logged in user data
        var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").Child(User.UserId).GetValueAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else if (DBTask.Result.Value == null)
        {
            //No data exists yet
        }
        else
        {
            //Data has been retrieved
            DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;
            if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("highscore"))
            {
                int i = 0;
                _MainMenuUI.instance.highScoreMainMenu.text = i.ToString();
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("higscore", int.Parse(_MainMenuUI.instance.highScoreMainMenu.text.ToString()));
                StartCoroutine(_FirebaseManager.instance.UpdateScoreDatabase(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("higscore")));
                _MainMenuUI.instance.highScoreMainMenu.text = snapshot.Child("highscore").Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                _MainMenuUI.instance.highScoreMainMenu.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore").ToString();
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("higscore", int.Parse(_MainMenuUI.instance.highScoreMainMenu.text.ToString()));
                StartCoroutine(_FirebaseManager.instance.UpdateScoreDatabase(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("higscore")));
            }

            if (_MainMenuUI.instance.usernameRegisterField.text != null)
            {
                _MainMenuUI.instance.usernameRegisterField.text = snapshot.Child("username").Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator LoadScoreboardData()
    {
        //Get all the users data ordered by kills amount
        var DBTask = DBreference.Child("users").OrderByChild("highscore").GetValueAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            //Data has been retrieved
            DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;

            //Destroy any existing scoreboard elements
            foreach (Transform child in _MainMenuUI.instance.scoreboardContent.transform)
            {
                Destroy(child.gameObject);
            }

            //Loop through every users UID
            foreach (DataSnapshot childSnapshot in snapshot.Children.Reverse<DataSnapshot>())
            {
                string username = childSnapshot.Child("username").Value.ToString();
                int highscore = int.Parse(childSnapshot.Child("highscore").Value.ToString());

                //Instantiate new scoreboard elements
                GameObject scoreboardElement = Instantiate(_MainMenuUI.instance.scoreElement, _MainMenuUI.instance.scoreboardContent);
                scoreboardElement.GetComponent<_ScoreElementContent>().NewScoreElement(username, highscore);
            }
            //Go to scoareboard screen
            _MainMenuUI.instance.leaderboardPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

oh also my bad if my code look very messy anyone can shorten it for the better, I appreciate it.

Comment: `if (_MainMenuUI.instance.usernameRegisterField.text != null)` try to make a check if the field is empty.

Comment: @zibelas,i've already check that